# Where can I find the question or answer I ever deal with?

Tags: support, recent-activity

All , As the title shows, sometimes I would like to find them which I ever commented, upvoted , downvoted or favorited. I didn't found it in my private user profile page, or is there something I didn't know? If there is, please kindly let me know it.

Comment: I can see your activity: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1553519/joe-wang?tab=activity . Could you tell us what happens when you go there?

Comment: Check your profile, its best place to find such things.

Comment: Oh, I found them in there :)  thanks your kindly comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All are available in [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553519/joe-wang).

- List of your comments [activity -> comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553519/joe-wang?tab=activity&sort=comments)
- upvoted posts [votes -> upvote*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553519/joe-wang?tab=votes&sort=upvote)
- downvoted posts [votes -> downvote*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553519/joe-wang?tab=votes&sort=upvote)
- [favorited questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553519/joe-wang?tab=favorites)

<sub>* Link for OP only. You can find it on your profile</sub>

Answer (score 2):

It's here in the activity tab
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/205546/joe-wang?tab=activity
I hope that's what you're looking for :)

Comment: Yeah , Thanks your help.